# AddProduct and isX64 functions not recognized in Inno Setup

Tags: inno-setup

Trying to call a subscript to install MS SQL server as part of an Inno Setup.

In the main script I include the subscript in the run section and call the procedure with the `BeforeInstall`:

```
[Run]
#include "MSSQLExpress2014WithTools.iss";
Filename: "{app}\{#MyAppExeName}"; Description: "{cm:LaunchProgram,{#StringChange(MyAppName, '&', '&&')}}"; Flags: nowait postinstall skipifsilent; BeforeInstall: sql2014express()
```

So far so good, but it seems like Inno Setup dislike my `MSSQLExpress2014WithTools.iss` subscript:

```
[CustomMessages]
sql2014expressx86_title=Microsoft SQL Server 2014 Express Edition x86 (Including Tools)
sql2014expressx64_title=Microsoft SQL Server 2014 Express Edition x64 (Including Tools)

sql2014expressx86_size=840.8 MB
sql2014expressx64_size=833.2 MB
```

```pascal
[Code]
const
  sql2014expressx86_url='http://download.microsoft.com/download/E/A/E/EAE6F7FC-767A-4038-A954-49B8B05D04EB/ExpressAndTools%2032BIT/SQLEXPRWT_x86_ENU.exe';
  sql2014expressx64_url='http://download.microsoft.com/download/E/A/E/EAE6F7FC-767A-4038-A954-49B8B05D04EB/ExpressAndTools%2064BIT/SQLEXPRWT_x64_ENU.exe';

procedure sql2014expresswithtools();
var
  version: string;

begin
  { Check if the full version fo the SQL Server 2014 is installed }
  RegQueryStringValue(HKLM, 'SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\SQLSERVER\MSSQLServer\CurrentVersion', 'CurrentVersion', version);
  if (version < '12') or (version = '') then 
  begin
    { If the full version is not found then check for the Express edition }
    RegQueryStringValue(HKLM, 'SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\SQLEXPRESS\MSSQLServer\CurrentVersion', 'CurrentVersion', version);
    if (version < '12') or (version = '') then 
    begin
      if isX64() then AddProduct('SQLEXPRWT_x64_ENU.exe', '/QS /IACCEPTSQLSERVERLICENSETERMS /ACTION=Install /FEATURES=SQL,AS,RS,IS,Tools /INSTANCENAME=SQLEXPRESS /SQLSVCACCOUNT="NT AUTHORITY\Network Service" /SQLSYSADMINACCOUNTS="builtin\Administrators" /INDICATEPROGRESS /TCPENABLED=1 /BROWSERSVCSTARTUPTYPE=Automatic /ERRORREPORTING=0 /SQMREPORTING=0 /SECURITYMODE=SQL /SAPWD=1234', CustomMessage('sql2014expressx64_title'), CustomMessage('sql2014expressx64_size'), sql2014expressx64_url,false,false)
      else AddProduct('SQLEXPRWT_x86_ENU.exe', '/QS /IACCEPTSQLSERVERLICENSETERMS /ACTION=Install /FEATURES=SQL,AS,RS,IS,Tools /INSTANCENAME=SQLEXPRESS /SQLSVCACCOUNT="NT AUTHORITY\Network Service" /SQLSYSADMINACCOUNTS="builtin\Administrators" /INDICATEPROGRESS /TCPENABLED=1 /BROWSERSVCSTARTUPTYPE=Automatic /ERRORREPORTING=0 /SQMREPORTING=0 /SECURITYMODE=SQL /SAPWD=1234', CustomMessage('sql2014expressx86_title'), CustomMessage('sql2014expressx86_size'), sql2014expressx86_url,false,false);
    end;
  end;
end;
```

It doesn't recognize the `AddProduct` and `isX64` functions.

Any hints appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no `AddProduct` or `isX64` function in Inno Setup.

You have probably based your code on some example, that uses some Inno Setup extension/addon, which adds these functions.

I assume the addon is [Inno Setup Dependency Installer](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/20868/Inno-Setup-Dependency-Installer), as it indeed defines functions with these names.